# C++: STRING Function returns hexadecimal value instead of string

Tags: c++

during my 2nd month learning C++ I got to this:
*STRING type function to build up and return menu from two user-input dishes*
(compliled and run in VisualStudio2013)

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

string LeMenu(string meal, string dessert) //a F() concatenates 2 strings
{
    return meal, dessert;  //also tried meal+dessert
}                   

int main()
{
    string course1, course2;
    cout << "What is your chice today Sir?\n";
    cin >> course1 >> course2;                  //request to input meals
    LeMenu(course1,course2);
    cout << "Is " << LeMenu << " ok?\n";        //here we output
    keep_window_open();
}
```

But it always returns a HEXADECIMAL VALUE, and I do not know why:
(compliled and run in VisualStudio2013)

```
Is 012D15CD ok?
```

instead of Is JamEggs ok? (as an example)

From what I have learnt I do not see why, my text book does not even suggests this as a likely issue and I can not find any hint on the internet!.
More than a way to solve it it would be nice to understand if this is an  expected mssbehavior or not. Thank you all!

Comment: Use `+` to concatenate `std::string`, not `,`

Comment: To explain further, `,` is a legal operator, but it doesn't do what you think (and you should avoid using it if you're learning C++, it won't be useful in most cases). `,` will evaluate the left expression, discard its result, evaluate the right expression and evaluate to the right expression's result (Edit: see [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other), not to be mistaken with commas in function calls/definitions or in initializer lists though).

Comment: Could these s****ing robo upvoters please stop to upvote each and every bad 1 rep user question here!

Comment: `#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"` looks very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << "Is " << LeMenu << " ok?\n";
```

Is printing the address of the function `LeMenu()` and not the returned string.  To print the returned string you would need to call the function like:

```
cout << "Is " << LeMenu(course1,course2) << " ok?\n";
```

Also

```
string LeMenu(string meal, string dessert) //a F() concatenates 2 strings
{
    return meal, dessert;  //also tried meal+dessert
}
```

Is not going to return a concatenated string.  It is using the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) and is only going to return the string `dessert`.  You need to include the `<string>` header and then you can use the `+` operator like

```
return meal + dessert;
```

Answer (score 4):

You are printing out the function address of `LeMenu`. Try this instead:

```
cout << "Is " << LeMenu(course1, course2) << " ok?\n";
```

Note that you are what you are returning is probably not what you want:

```
return meal, dessert; //Only returns dessert
```

You probably want:

```
return meal + dessert;
```

Answer (score 2):

In

```
cout << "Is " << LeMenu << " ok?\n";
```

you print the address of the function.

you want

```
cout << "Is " << LeMenu(course1, course2) << " ok?\n";
```